# jquery find next but not exactly next within parent

Tags: jquery

My problem is
I have html like:

```
<ul id="myblock">
  <li id="first" class="myele">list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li class="myele">list item 3</li>
  <li class="myele">list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
</ul>
```

now i want to find next element from "list item 1" with having class "myele" so how to do that?

currently I am using

```
$("#first").next(".myele")
```

but its not working because its not exactly next to it

Comment: maybe https://api.jquery.com/siblings/ ?

Comment: try `$("#first").siblings(".myele").first()`

Comment: but how to get next sibling?

Comment: ```$("#first").parent().next(".myele").first()```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [.nextAll()](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) to do this:

```js
console.log($("#first").nextAll(".myele").first())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myblock">
  <li id="first" class="myele">list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li class="myele">list item 3</li>
  <li class="myele">list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: perfect and very simple

Comment: FYI, Using `[0]` may cause errors like `undefined`. Instead use [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) or [`first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/) or [`get(0)`](https://api.jquery.com/get/)

Comment: `first()` may be a better solution. Thank you @User863

Answer (score 1):

You also can use `siblings` method, if you want first item use `.first()` method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#first").siblings(".myele").css('color', 'red');
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#first").siblings(".myele").first().css('color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myblock">
  <li id="first" class="myele">list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li class="myele">list item 3</li>
  <li class="myele">list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `siblings` return all siblings, not just the next. So if starting with list item 4, the result will be list item 1.